# Youtube embeded video allowed to be changed by admin

Tags: html, youtube

I need to embed a youtube video into my site but I need to allow certain people to be able to change the video that is shown without them going into code, How would I do this?

Another thing that could help is how could I automatically embed someones latest video onto the site.

If anyone can answer any of these thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For adding a YouTube video without going into the code you could look at [Google Tag Manager](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/) or a similar service. For embedding the latest video you might need to look at a YouTube API or similar to pull in the latest videos url.